# Is there a Drupal function to get all nodes from a taxnomy and his children

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have taxonomies and sub-taxonomies :

```
 - MainTaxo
    - SubTaxo1
    - SubTaxo2
```

[taxonomy_select_nodes](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/7) give me all ids of the selected taxonomy but if I put the MainTaxo id, it don't return me ids of SubTaxo1 and SubTaxo2.

```
$ids = taxonomy_select_nodes($mainTaxonomy_id, false);
```

Is there a native drupal function or should I do a query for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is finally what I did :

```
/**
 * function to get all node ids recursively inside a taxonomy term.
 * Returns Flat array of nids.
 * @param
 *   $tid takes tid for which you need nids recursively.
 * @return
 *   $nids flat array of nids
 */
function get_all_nodes_belong_to_taxonomy_hierarchy($tid) {
  $taxonomies   = array('parent' => (int)$tid);
  $taxonomies = $taxonomies + array_keys(taxonomy_get_children($tid));
  $nids = array();

  foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy_id) {
    $nodes = taxonomy_select_nodes($taxonomy_id, false);
    $nids = array_merge_recursive($nids, $nodes);
  }
  return $nids;
}
```

Comment: That's a beautiful function name.

Answer (score 2):

There isnt a native Drupal function, but in this link there are alternatives!

https://drupal.org/node/1946346

I hope it has useful.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately `get_all_nodes_belong_to_taxonomy_hierarchy` don't return me all my nodes so I did my own function with the inspiration of your link.